# C++ std::list segmentation fault with different compiling order

Tags: c++, stl, global-variables, static-variables, stdlist

I have the following testing program:

```cpp
// manager.h
#pragma once

#include <list>

namespace testapp
{
    class Manager
    {
    public:
        static Manager& instance();
        void addItem(int val);

    private:
        std::list<int> m_items;
    };

    template <int N>
    class Helper
    {
    public:
        Helper()
        {
            Manager::instance().addItem(N);
        }
    };
}

// manager.cpp
#include "manager.h"

namespace testapp
{
    static Manager s_global_instance;
    Manager& Manager::instance()
    {
        return s_global_instance;
    }

    void Manager::addItem(int val)
    {
        m_items.push_back(val);
    }
}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "manager.h"

namespace testapp
{
    Helper<1> helper;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "It works!\n";
}
```

When I build this app with the following command line:

```bash
g++ main.cpp manager.cpp -std=c++2a -o TestApp
```

I got `Segmentation fault`, which is triggered in `m_items.push_back(val)`.

However, if I build this app with different source order:

```bash
g++ manager.cpp main.cpp -std=c++2a -o TestApp
```

The program works as expected. I can the output `It works!` without any error.

After some investigation, I found that the problem is `s_global_instance` seems not fully initialized when `Helper<1> helper` gets instantiated. What I mean here is the member `std::list<int> m_items` is not initialized (properly) when global static variable `s_global_instance` is used. When `addItem` gets called, I stepped into `push_back`, I found that the head node is not actually initialized. It gets initialized after `addItem` getting called.

If I change `static Manager s_global_instance` to a local static variable like this:

```cpp
Manager& Manager::instance()
{
   static Manager _instance;
   return _instance;
}
```

It's always working. No segmentation fault no matter which command line I use as showing above. The source file order doesn't matter any more.

My questions are here:

- Why compiling order matters when global static variable is used?
- Why local static variable works?
- Is this issue related to template instantiation?
- What is the initialization order when static variable, global static variable, global variable and template involved?

Comment: There's a phrase, [*static initialization order fiasco*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) and I suspect the file order influences the initialization order here. But yeah, the usual way is to have your singleton be a local static variable of the singleton getter function.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller. Yes, the proper solution here is to use local static variable instead of global static variable. I have the same feeling of the initialization issue here caused by the compiling order, but can't well explain what actually happens here. This link is very helpful and the video in the link probably has more insight. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: What actually happens is pretty simple. You have two global variables, `s_global_instance` and `helper`, defined in two different translation units. Both have non-trivial constructors. These constructors are guaranteed to be called some time before `main`, but it's unspecified which one is called first. When `helper` happens to be constructed first, its constructor calls a method on `s_global_instance` whose lifetime hasn't started yet, whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: A local static variable is initialized on first use, when control passes over its definition for the first time (this initialization is automatically thread-safe, the compiler inserts necessary synchronization; not that it matters in your example). So `helper` constructor runs and calls `Manager::instance()` which in turn causes `_instance` to be constructed.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with templates. You can make `Helper` a non-template class that just hard-codes `addItem(1)`, and should observe the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik. Your explanation is very helpful. It clears my confusion. Thank you very much.